# Filtrando eventos para Triggers

Tags: c#, sql-server, trigger

Estou com um contra tempo que estou quebrando a cabeça mais não consigo resolver. Tenho uma tabela no qual gostaria que sempre que fosse inserido, alterado ou deletado um dado, disparasse uma trigger e adiciona-se o dado em uma tabela chamada log. Meu trigger está assim:

```
string sql = "CREATE TRIGGER Historico_Contacts ON Contacts " +
                    "FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE AS " +
                    "BEGIN " +
                    "INSERT INTO Logs (Id, DataModificacao, Acao) SELECT Id, DataModificacao = GETDATE(), Acao = 'INSERT' from INSERTED " +
                    "INSERT INTO Logs (Id, DataModificacao, Acao) SELECT Id, DataModificacao = GETDATE(), Acao = 'DELETE' from DELETED " +
                    //"SELECT Id, DataModificacao = GETDATE(), Acao = 'INSERT' from inserted " +
                    //"SELECT Id, DataModificacao = GETDATE(), Acao = 'DELETE' from deleted " +
                    //"SELECT Id, DataModificacao = GETDATE(), Acao = 'UPDATE' from deleted " +
                    "END;";
```

Como podem ver, já tentei vários métodos. O principal problema que estou tendo é que quando faço alteração no dado, ele continua registrado como se fosse inserido o dado. Sei que estou esquecendo alguma coisa, mais não sei o que.
Obs.: Esse código da trigger é executado em uma aplicação C#.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers são gerenciadas pelo próprio banco de dados, são diferentes de procedures que você consegue executar via código.

Tente da seguinte maneira:

**1 - Criar a trigger dentro do seu banco de dados**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_HISTORICO_CONTATO ON CONTATOS 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO LOGS SELECT ID, GETDATE(), 'Novo contato inserido' FROM INSERTED
    
END
```

**2 - Execute o insert via código, que a sua trigger está esperando para ser executada**

```
INSERT INTO CONTATO ( COL ....
```

dentro de seu banco de dados

Comment: Beleza amigo. Então só para eu ver se entendi direito, vou ter criar um gatilho separado para cada evento (INSERT, DELETE UPDATE)?

Comment: @MarcosHenrique não, você poder criar exatamente como você criou no seu código acima ( com as outras operações ), porém você só precisa ter em mente que as trigger precisam ser criadas dentro do banco de dados, e o que fica no seu código são apenas as operações de DML ( insert, update, select e delete )